# Create new JSON Object List considting of specific Fields from another Object List

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

How do I create a JSON List of only specific object fields (columns(?)) from another JSON list?

I need to create a JSON Object list where the Fields and the values of the new list are taken from another existing list where the existing field is a specific one I want.

For example, a user will select a CSVfile, I extract the data into a JSON List (using papaparse), this CSV can have any number of columns, but I only need 4 of them. These 4 columns will always have the same header name which when I pass the data to JSON becomes the field name. How can I make a new list only with the entire values from fields called e.g. "IdApplication" and "AccountNumber"?

So if I have a JSON from user like:

```
$scope.TestList = [
   {id: 1, name: 'Bob', age: 23, bio: 'Duck Toaster'},
   {id: 2, name: 'Tom', age: 69, bio: 'Banana Sharks'}
];
```

How can I take only the id and age fields and make a new list like:

```
$scope.NewTestList = [
   {id: 1, age: 23},
   {id: 2, age: 69}
];
```

I've looked in to .push() and so for looping through each object and adding to a new list, but that appears to only add a new item to an array ad not a new object to an array. Also ideally not having to loop through tens of thousands of list objects to addto another list would be nice, a way to mass add ideally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Array `map()` method;

```
$scope.NewTestList = $scope.TestList.map(el => ({
    id: el.id,
  name: el.name
}));
```

Comment: @Vereonix Beware of browser support there, array.map() is not supported in older versions of IE

Comment: @Protozoid If by older you mean IE < 9, then yes. ;) Then again, what does it support? :)

Comment: @vicbyte You're right, it's a pile of cr*p, but unfortunately it sometimes has to be supported for the users stuck on non-admin rights company PCs

Comment: @vicbyte How would I map a field which name has a space in it?

Comment: @Vereonix Use bracket notation, ie. el['name']

Comment: @vicbyte I've been a fool and only just tested this in IE11+ and it gives a syntax error for the "=>" after el, any ideas how t ofix this? It works fine in Chrome and FF.

Comment: Use `function(){}` instead of arrow functions `el => {}`. IE doesnt support the latter. Or just use a transpiler (typescript for ex.)

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through each object in `$scope.TestList` and push only what you want in your `$scope.NewTestList`

```
$scope.NewTestList = [];
angular.forEach($scope.TestList, function (testItem) {
    $scope.NewTestList.push({
        'id': testItem.id,
        'age': testItem.age
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the code below

```
let newTestList = TestList.map(obj => {
                     return { id: obj.id, age: obj.age } 
                  }
```

This will map over your array and return a new array with the respective properties and values

Answer (score 0):

You can do in a very simple way using the forEach syntax:

```
var arr1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'sasa', age: 13 }, 
            { id: 2, name: 'sfsdasa', age: 21 }, 
            { id: 3, name: 'dsdssasa', age: 14 }];
var arr2 = []; // create an empty array
arr1.forEach(function(arr) {
    arr2.push({id:arr.id,age:arr.age}) // push in the array
}, this);
console.log(arr2)
```